# Javascript private fields: why "#" instead of "_"?

Tags: javascript

Why Javascript decided to go with "#" (hash) prefix for private fields, instead of the traditional convention "_" (underscore) we see in other languages?

As described in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

```
class ClassWithPrivateField {   
  #privateField
}
```

Comment: There's a committee that governs changes to the language, and that's the decision they made. Using `#` allows for a new feature that cannot affect older working code.

Comment: TL;DR: backwards compatibility. `_` is already used today as a mere *convention*.

Comment: how is the question opinion based ? anyways here's the official FAQ https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-was-the-sigil--chosen-among-all-the-unicode-code-points

Comment: @Pointy Instead of writing a short-hand answer in a comment, why not post an answer?

Comment: @Nit I think this is a many-times-over duplicate

Comment: @Pointy In that case, wouldn't it be better to close it as a duplicate instead of opinion-based? If it's a many-times-over duplicate as you say, there's surely interest around it and would be good to have one canonical source to link to.

Comment: @Nit I am terrible at actually *finding* duplicates. And really, it doesn't matter; this question is of low value to the JavaScript community.

Comment: the proof this question is not opinion based is that there's a very OBJECTIVE answer right from the TC39 group, as pointed out by @jonatjano comment

Comment: @Pointy While this is a very subjective opinion, if a question comes up so much that it becomes a many-times-over duplicate, then I would say that there's clearly value to the community. Even if it isn't directly applicable to the code you write, understanding the rationale behind why and how the language you use evolves can be very valuable insight.